# Logic gate latch application question

Tags: digital-logic, latch

I am trying to design a reliable latch to lock the output of U3 permanently high when the Q14 goes high and I couldn't find a solution after searching online, so I came up with the following circuit using 2 NAND gates (U3 and U4) and a diode D1. When the output of Q14 goes high so does the U3 and this state is maintained via feedback of R4 and when Q14 goes low, the U3 maintains its high state because the D1 is reverse biased and the input of U4 remains high. Do you think this is a good solution or it can be improved?

Kindest regards

[image]

Comment: Is a latch IC infeasible? If so, can you clarify the design constraints that make it so, by [edit]ing your question?

Comment: There are many ways to have a latch function, including buying a latch. The way you illustrate is useful if you have spare inverting gates lying around, presumably you need U2 (and U1 wherever that is) so get U3 and U4 for free.

Comment: FYI, I would mirror your schematic around the Y-axis. Standard practice is having inputs left, and outputs going to the right.

Comment: Yes I prefer to use CD4093 NAND gate IC because one of the gates is already been used for PWR On reset and I'd imagine it wouldn't be hard to use the remaining gates to design a simple latch as it's common with logic gates.

Comment: When the output is 1 (high), how will it ever get back to 0 (low)? *By switching the supply off and on again.* Are you sure it will then start at output = 0 ? What if it starts with output = 1? The circuit has no reason to startup with output = 0. I think you will need to make a proper R/S flip-flop. Furtunately, that can be done with a few NAND gates. You will also need a power-on-reset which you already have.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I had a look at SR latch, but the version with two NAND gates seems not to work as they have two inputs that just flip the outputs or maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: *not to work as they have two inputs that just flip the outputs* How about one input is SET and the other is RESET? Two inputs sounds just right to me.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is very inventive. It has an issue which @TonyStewartEE75 alluded to, regarding startup state, but otherwise it would work just fine. I would recommend R4 be much lower, say 10kΩ, but the idea is great.

My own approach would involve a SR ("set-reset") flipflop, which is the "defacto" solution to simple latching problems. Something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8VNEI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

C1 and R1 create a signal that stays high for a few milliseconds following power-on, eventually becoming low, and this forces the top NOR gate to initially output low.

D1 isn't strictly necessary, because most logic ICs these days contain input protection diodes that would perform the same function, but it's there to prevent the gate's input becoming negative when power is removed, and to discharge the capacitor immediately when that happens.

When the input "IN" is taken high, the bottom NOR gate output is forced low, which in turn sends the top gate output "OUT" high. Mutual feedback between the two gates maintains this new state.

You can do this with NAND gates, but you'll need to pay attention to signal polarites.

By the way, signal paths from right to left are not recommended, unless absolutely necessary. I had to turn my mind upside down for a second or two.

***Note:*** I notice you already have a power-on reset signal. You can use this instead of the separate R1/C1/D1 I used in my example. If you use NAND gates to form the latch, you will require an initially-low signal to force one of the pair of NAND gates into an output-high state, either from the input of U2-NAND2, or an inverted version of its output.

Comment: Very Nice indeed. Sorry for the circuit direction. Since I am using NAND gates, should I inverse the input of top gate?

Comment: @Baphomet I made a mistake with the position of D1. Fixed now. If you mean swap R1 and C1, then yes, that will create a momentary low, necessary to guarantee an initial NAND high output. D1 always across R1, always pointing up. You may have to invert the output from U1 prior to the NAND input. I'll let you figure out why.